# try/catch error handling in web app

Tags: google-apps-script, error-handling, web-applications

I noticed that when an error is thrown in a try/catch block within a Google Apps Script, `Logger.log(e instanceof Error)` returns true. But, when that same object is passed back to the client in the `catch` statement, it logs `false`.

**GAS sample**

```js
function isValid() {
  return false
}

function testing() {
  try {
    if(!isValid()) { throw new Error("failure") }
    return "success"
  } catch(e) {
    Logger.log(e instanceof Error) // true
    return e // false in the client when tested with console.log(e instanceof Error)
  }
}
```

**client**

```js
function foo() {
 google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(onSuccess).withFailureHandler(onFailure).testing();
}

function onSuccess(e) {
  console.log(e instanceof Error) // false
  console.log(e) // null
}

function onFailure(e) {
  console.log(e instanceof Error) // no result
}
```

Is there a better way to test for an error returned from the script file?

Comment: The code is server-side code. How are you passing the server-side error to the client-side?

Comment: Updated with a client sample. `onSuccess` logs e as `null` if an error is thrown in the statement. `onFailure` is never called.

Comment: The problem is you are `return`ing e. you need to `throw` it. see my answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the client side, you use a `.withFailureHandler(...)` when calling the [`.run.myFunction()`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/html/reference/run) code. The failure handler is a function in your client side code that will be called if an exception (i.e. error) is thrown in your server-side code *and not handled*.

Failure handlers will only be called if an exception is thrown. Otherwise, the success handler receives the server-side function's `return` value.

.gs

```
function myFn() {
  try {
    throw new Error("failure");
  }
  catch (e) {
    Logger.log(e);
    // Must rethrow to activate the client's FailureHandler function.
    throw e;
  }
  return "success"
}
```

.html

```
function foo() {
  google.script.run.withFailureHandler(logError).withSuccessHandler(useReturnValue).myFn();
}
function logError(error) {
  console.log(error);
}
function useReturnValue(value) {
  // do stuff
}
```

In the client side console, you will see the error get logged.

Comment: That was it. I didn't know it needed to be rethrown. I thought it would pass it directly to the client. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that your `e` variable hasn't an object assigned. Please note that the official Guides use  `error` as the error handling function argument but your code use `data` and instead of using it on the console statement you use `e`.

On your client-side code replace `data` by `e` or vice versa.

From https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/html/reference/run#withFailureHandler(Function)

#### Code.gs

```
function doGet() {
  return HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile('Index');
}

function getUnreadEmails() {
  // 'got' instead of 'get' will throw an error.
  return GmailApp.gotInboxUnreadCount();
}
```

#### index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <base target="_top">
    <script>
      function onFailure(error) {
        var div = document.getElementById('output');
        div.innerHTML = "ERROR: " + error.message;
      }

      google.script.run.withFailureHandler(onFailure)
          .getUnreadEmails();
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="output"></div>
  </body>
</html>
```